# No such element exception in jsp with spring tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have a jsp in that i am using two spring tab lib i.e

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

if i comment these two my jsp is executing fine. but in other case it is throwing above exception this is my exception stack trace.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1385)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1262)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:876)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1841)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at in.nic.rgpsa.dispatcher.RGPSADispatcher.doService(RGPSADispatcher.java:18)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at in.nic.rgpsa.intercepter.UserFilter.doFilter(UserFilter.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at in.nic.rgpsa.intercepter.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my implemented an application using spring as dynamic web project this is not a spring boot application and i have spring 3.2.2 jar in my class path, 
can any body please tell me where i am causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both Spring's taglibs are supported by Spring MVC. You need to download spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar (to remain consistent with your current version) and copy the library to the WEB-INF/lib folder of your application.

EDIT: Here is the Maven dependency tree of a working prototype (with taglibs and Spring 3.2.2).

```
demo:spring-mvc-demo:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
 +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
```

The code is running on Jetty 9.2.17. You could check your Tomcat instance has JSTL in its lib folder.

Comment: i already added in lib folder and all my spring jars are with 3.2 version ,anything else

Comment: Then, we could assume this has to do with the JSP itself. Could you post it ? Do you use any of the Spring tags?

Comment: thanks for your reply my application is not maven it is dynamic web project  and i have all the jars in my lib which you specified above still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: Then, have you checked that JSTL is in the lib folder of your Tomcat? By the way; which version of Tomcat is it? Since you're using quite an old version of Spring, you might be using an old Tomcat too. I wonder if your taglibs get automatically registered or if you need to register the TLDs manually like we used to do back in the days :-).

Comment: jstl jar is in lib not in tomcat lib and i am using tomcat 7 is spring 3.2.2 is not recommended version to use